# Como declarar uma constante em Ruby?

Tags: ruby, constantes

Como declarar uma constante em Ruby? Em outras linguagens faço algo como:

```
const CONSTANTE = 1024
```

E `CONSTANTE` **não pode ser alterado** em tempo de execução. Mas não acho nada parecido em Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby não tem constantes "de verdade".

Como [o @Maniero disse na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254947/18246), é possível usar a convenção de escrever o nome da variável com a primeira letra maiúscula. Isso vai fazer com que o interpretador gere um *warning*, dizendo que o valor contido ali não deveria ser reatribuído.

Isso, infelizmente, pode não cobrir todos os casos. Então, a minha dica é criar uma função para estes casos especiais.

É claro que isso pode ser um exagero, precisa-se analisar com cuidado antes de tomar este tipo de decisão.

Um exemplo do que eu disse é fazer:

```
def constante()
    return 1024
end

puts constante()
```

<sup>**Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UsableDirtyWyvern) | [RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/c2bf3)**</sup>

Comment: Acredito ser o único workaround para uma constante de verdade nessa linguagem.

Comment: @vnbrs Sinceramente, eu também. Tem casos em que arriscar é dar margem pra erros que não podem acontecer.

Answer (score 9):

Uma das coisas que eu gosto em Ruby é a adoção da filosofia *convention over configuration*. Isso quer dizer que existe uma forma que você usa algo e a linguagem sabe o que fazer, em detrimento a você ter que dizer o que quer. Então enquanto outras linguagens exigem que faça:

```
const constante = 1
```

Ruby só precisa fazer:

```
Constante = 1
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Constant.rb).

Pode estar pensando, mas o que isso difere da variável? Simples, o nome está começando com maiúsculo, esse fato já diz que é uma constante. As variáveis precisam obrigatoriamente começar com minúsculo.

Isso inclusive tem a vantagem que não existe declaração padrão implícita. Você está sempre sendo explícito sem criar ruído no texto.

Note que não gera um erro, apenas um alerta, então é permitido alterar o valor se quiser mesmo. Não há uma constante verdadeira em Ruby. É apenas uma declaração de intenção.

É a mesma coisa que `estado` e `Estado`, dependendo da ortografia, são coisas bem diferentes.

Não gosto de todas convenções que Ruby adotou, mas a ideia geral é muito legal.

Algumas pessoas preferem colocar tudo maiúsculo, mas não é obrigatório e eu não gosto.

Comment: **Por convenção** é usado o nome todo em maiúsculo separando as palavras com o '_', como por exemplo: MINHA_CONSTANTE = 15.

Comment: @HamurabiAraujo convenção de algumas pessoas, não da linguagem, a linguagem só olha o primeiro caractere.

Comment: Sim, claro. Apenas um padrão adotado pela comunidade. Obrigado pela ressalva.

Comment: É uma constante ou variável? Veja [rodando](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/3911f).

Comment: @vnbrs editei para colocar isto.

Answer (score -1):

Use o `#freeze`

```
CONSTANTE = "valor".freeze
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/freeze

Comment: O `Object#freeze` é interessante, mas não faz uma constante. Ele trava a instância de objeto. Por exemplo: `"constante".freeze.upcase!` gera um `FrozenError`.